# Changing a specific "cell" in a Pandas DataFrame using a conditional on that "cell" but after finding the end of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

***Edited with more info***

I am relatively new to stack, and to Pandas.  I have tried to find answers on how, but cannot find a definitive answer and I put it to the hive mind.

- I have data stored in a variable (from MQTT that needs to be added to index 5.  Before it gets added I first need to find the last entry of the ID "12345" and then get the value of the matching TYPE .

Then, I need to add the new data from the variable into index 5 with the opposite of what is there in the filtered series.  If the filtered series displays a "" or "out" then create new entry with the data in the variable but put "in" if the value is "in" create new entry and place "out".

So I have a df with just 4 columns

```
ID  DATE    TIME    TYPE

0   12345   20200518    2018    IN

1   22345   20200518    2019    IN

2   32345   20200518    2036    IN

3   42345   20200518    2105    IN

4   12345   20200518    2201    OUT
```

I want to find the last value entry of "12345" (I can do this using `filt = df['ID'] == IDT` where IDT = 12345 which gives me the last series with that value (12345). Once I have found the series I then want to "read" the value in the TYPE "cell" based on whats already in there, and then put the opposite underneath to create a new record.

If it is a "" or "Out" then change it to "IN" but add it to the df (not overwrite the filtered result)

In essence it is to keep track of an RFID system and line 5 should be

```
5   12345   20200518   2343   IN.
```

---

New code here

Thank you for replying.  I added that to my code.  I had to play around with it to get the errors out of the way and well there is a point I can't get passed.  Here is the the entire script (I know I need some automation in there to keep the script going through and also some if statements to stop the file duplicating some text inside etc.

This is the error log:  Caught exception in on_message: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

```
import datetime
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



# message = ("id2436520201757") used for testing

today =  datetime.date.today()
filename = str(today)

# opens a file with todays date and adds headers, this
with open(filename + ".csv", "a") as hashsearch:
    hashsearch.write("ID,DATE,TIME,TYPE \n")
    hashsearch.close()

df = pd.read_csv(filename + ".csv")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received from phone " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)


# trying to find last entry of value and replace it in new line below...

    msg = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))

    idx = (msg[2:7])

    print(idx, 'this is the new msg index')

    last_idx = df.loc[df['ID'] == idx].index[-1]
    last_entry = df['TYPE'][last_idx]
    if last_entry == 'OUT' or last_entry == '':
        new_entry = 'IN'
    elif last_entry == 'IN':
       new_entry = 'OUT'



    print(last_idx, "   ", last_entry, "   ", new_entry)

    payload = ("ID: " + msg[2:7] + " " + "DATE: " + msg [7:13] + " " + "TIME: " + msg [13:17] + new_entry + "\n")   



    with open(filename + ".csv", "a") as f:
        f.write(payload, "this should have all data in")



def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print("log: ",buf)
########################################
broker_address="192.168.0.46"
print("creating new instance")
client = mqtt.Client("esp2") #create new instance
client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback
print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address) #connect to broker
client.loop_start() #start the loop
print("Subscribing to topic","door")
client.subscribe("door")
print("Publishing message to topic","window")
client.publish("window","OFF")
client.on_log=on_log
time.sleep(10) # wait
client.loop_stop() #stop the loop
```

I thank you in advance for any help you may give on how to achieve the above.

Cheers,

J

Answer (score 0):

So after having read your edit, I think I get what you want. You can find the 'opposite' entry as follows

```
IDT = 12345
# find the index in df corresponding to the last entry of IDT
last_idx = df.loc[df['ID'] == IDT].index[-1]

last_entry = df['TYPE'][last_idx]
if last_entry == 'OUT' or last_entry == '':
    new_entry = 'IN'
elif last_entry == 'IN':
    new_entry = 'OUT'
```

Now you can alter the data that you have from MQTT by setting its `'TYPE'` column entry to `new_entry` and append it to the dataframe using `df = df.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I may of not been clear.  I am not only searching for "" or "out"  as there may already be the value of "in" there. So basically if there is an "" or "out" place in there on next line with rest of data or if "in" place "out" i used `IDT = 12345` and then ` filt = df['ID'] == IDT ` to filter out to the last in the series.

Comment: I have edited to the main with more info.  Hope its clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am getting an error so will reply with all the code in the main original question

Sorry if this is not "etiquette"

New error is:

log:  Caught exception in on_message: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: That just means that there is no entry in the `'ID'` column matching `IDT`, hence the Series returned by `df.loc` is of size zero. You can add a conditional checking for this, and only proceed if the length of the returned Series is greater than 0.